# Given an array of arrays, I want to call a function passing each array as arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I have an array of arrays:

```
var data = [[2,2], [6,4], [300,500]];
```

I have a function that takes some arguments and returns a single value.

```
var sum = function (a, b) { return a + b; }
```

I want to apply the function to each item in the array, e.g.

```
FOO(data, sum) === [sum(2,2), sum(6,4), sum(300,500)] === [4, 10, 800]
```

I was hoping underscore would have a function that does what "FOO" does. But I don't see anything. `_.map` is close, but not quite.

I know how to implement the function FOO.

```
var FOO = function (arrayOfArrays, iterator, context) { 
    return _.map(arrayOfArrays, function (array) { 
        return iterator.apply(context, array); 
    }
)};
```

**My question is what to call *FOO*.** I'm guessing the above pattern is common enough in functional programming that there's already a well established, language-agnostic name for this function.

Comment: *what to call FOO*? Call it whatever you want, you are the author. I would call it `Unicorn`! If futur users hate the name you chose, well you can always change it and deprecate the old name!

Comment: well, you're basically calling a reduce function on each mapped element on the array, so map-reduce?

Comment: Basic building block functions like these tend to have common names that are used all over the place, e.g. map, reduce, first, rest, debounce, throttle, sort, shuffle, min, max. I'm not asking for suggestions -- I can come up with my own name. What I'm asking is if there's one already in common use. I know it's a weird question.

Comment: So you want to apply some function (which may or may not be `sum`) to each element of an array and collect the results in another array? Sounds like `map` to me. What is the difference between what you're doing and what `map` does? You say that `map` is close but I don't see the difference.

Comment: @muistooshort `_.map(data, sum) === [sum([2,2], 0), sum([6,4], 1), sum([300,500],2)]`. Not quite what I want. I don't want to pass the array to the iterator. I want to unroll the array and pass each of its  elements as a separate argument.

Comment: @muistooshort Had to edit the example in the question because it had extra [s where they shouldn't have been. That probably contributed to your not seeing the difference.

Comment: I see, you want it to behave as though `sum` was `function() { return arguments[0][0] + arguments[0][1] }`, right?

Comment: If there's a name for this pattern, I don't know it.  However, you could name the iterator instead of the wrapper, or use something like `_.map(data, _.partial(Function.prototype.apply, null), sum);`.

Comment: @psaquared Yes, that works too but I really want a function so the code is easy to read in the future (given that one has already become familiar with that particular function). I like the idea of naming the iterator instead. Then the code would be '_.map(data, BAR(sum))'. The question becomes what to call BAR, a higher order function that turns 'f(a,b,c...)' into 'f([a,b,c...])'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there is already a standard Javascript method for arrays, forEach(), that does what you want. For example:

```
data.forEach(sum);
```

So, do you really need a new FOO? If so, you could name it "forEach" and just wrap the above logic.